# Bluetooth is turned on, but I don't have a Bluetooth device

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

Firstly, I have to say this is more an annoyance / bug rather than something being broken or not working.

In my Action Center the Bluetooth Square is blue (turned on) saying *Not Connected*.

Here's the thing though - My PC doesn't have any Bluetooth capable hardware components. It's not a laptop, the motherboard doesn't have this functionality, and no devices connected to it have Bluetooth features either.

I've researched online and most suggestions revolve around

- *turning Bluetooth off* - I can't do as there is no on/off switch in the settings
- *removing the Bluetooth device from device manager* - I also can't do, as there isn't a Bluetooth device listed there.
- *going into network settings and disabling it there* - I can't disable it from network settings as there is no network adapter to do so.
- *Unpin Bluetooth tile from Quick Actions* - It isn't in the quick actions list to add/remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the Action Center and unpin he **Bluetooth** tile. Right-click on any item & select **Edit quick actions**.
[image]
[image]

Edit: How about right-clicking on the '**Collapse**' header? That gives me the option to '**Edit**':
[image]

Comment: The only option when I right-click is to go to settings, which takes me to *Bluetooth and other devices* which doesn't help (I'm sure I used to be able to do that though - was that removed in an update?). I can get to this by going into settings->System->Notifications&Actions manually though, however, **Bluetooth is not listed here to add or remove**.

Comment: If I right-click on the '**Collapse**' header, I get a slightly differently worded option, **Edit**, wheich also allows me to unpin tiles. Does that appear for you? See edited answer.

Comment: Still no dice, the only way I can see to edit them is to go into the *notification and actions* settings section. From there I can only rearrange the tiles, or go into *add or remove quick actions* which has on/off sliders, but doesn't list Bluetooth as an option. *Windows Pro 1809*

Comment: Ok well that was weird. On the *Add or remove quick actions* screen, I turned ***Network*** off, and both *Network **and** Bluetooth* tiles disappeared. When I turned the *Network* one back on, only the **Network** tile appeared again.

Comment: I feel like your answer is only millimetres away from being chosen as the correct answer - that this is just a graphical UI bug/glitch, and messing with the tiles would get rid of it. if you could add *try turning off network (or other) tiles and turning them back on* I would accept this as the answer! (who would guess turning things off+on would fix stuff)

Answer (score 4):

### Stop and Disable all Bluetooth Services on Windows 10 with PowerShell

Consider using PowerShell and perhaps running it as a startup script which will run in the system security context. You can use [Group Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy) or [Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) to set it to run at startup, etc.

**PowerShell**

```
## -- Store all bluetooth named services as an array, stop processes if running, and disable the startup type if it's not already
$BTServices = (Get-Service | ?{$_.DisplayName -match "bluetooth"}).Name;

$BTServices | % {
    $status = (Get-Service -Name $_).Status;
    If($status -ne "Stopped"){Stop-Service $_ -Force};
    $sType  = (Get-Service -Name $_).StartType;
    If($sType -ne "Disabled"){Set-Service $_ -StartupType Disabled};
    };
```

Furthermore, consider going into your BIOS\UEFI configurations and setting any applicable bluetooth related settings to a disabled or an equivalent value for additional thoroughness at that level.

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)

Comment: Do I correctly assume you have this as a startup script so as to prevent any possibility these services become re-enabled? Or for some other reason? I don't see the connection between using a startup script and the services running with the SYSTEM account.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator This is correct that I use these in an environment in which if the startup script stops and disables the applicable services, then it is assured these won't typically be started for any other reason afterwards. If your case is similar, then this should suite your need but obviously you'll want to test and confirm in your environment to be 100% certain. The startup script in my case runs at every startup so if there are issues, typically a reboot of the machine will resolve issues with the services otherwise I suppose.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home tonight, and post the result

Comment: Funny thing - I never got around to trying this, as I got rid of it by accident (see other answer)

Comment: @Smock Just realized I never heard back on this? Any particular update?